# Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function after updating to Angular 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I recently updated my Angular project to Angular 7. Now, when I run "ng serve --open" from the CLI, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function
>       at ReflectionCapabilities._ownParameters (core.js:1394)
>       at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (core.js:1426)
>       at JitReflector.parameters (platform-browser-dynamic.js:48)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:10202)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:10155)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:9784)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:9647)
>       at _filterJitIdentifiers.forEach (compiler.js:23148)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at _filterJitIdentifiers.forEach (compiler.js:23147)

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.1.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.1",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "./app/*"
      ]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015"
  }
}
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "node_modules/ng-drag-drop/style.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "node_modules/ng2-drag-drop/style.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "frontend-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "frontend",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

I assume that there are some dependency errors (currently, when I run "npm audit fix", NPM shows me that the auth0/angular-jwt library needs Angular 6, there is already a GitHub issue, but even if I remove that library temporary, the error still occurs).

**Edit:** When I run `ng serve --open --aot` it works. But why?

Comment: Hey! Did you solve?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Not even after the update to Angular 7.0.2. As said, with --aot, it works, but it takes a loooong time when it's recompiling after changes.

Comment: I'm on 7.0.2 and it happens when NOT using es5 as target. Bah

Comment: Es5 works fine basically.

Comment: Ha, you guys are right! 7.0.2 with target es5 works.
Well, thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah but I'd like to target es2015 hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Angular released a newer version `7.0.2`
this bug should be fixed,
run `ng update --all` to update

Comment: I tried, but still got the same error. Do I need to clean npm cache?